# Docker daemon stops on Mac OSX sleep

Tags: macos, docker

Its frustrating to restart my container each time I am back to desktop as docker service is killed as soon as Mac OSx (Yosemite) sleeps.

I am looking to keep the daemon running so my containers are still accessible. I tried by enabling [live-restore](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/live-restore/#enable-live-restore), but that is still not working .

## Edit

Any one looking for answer, [this](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/85#issuecomment-315645640) fixed my issue, after stopping the daemon run following.

```
cd ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/database
git reset --hard
echo "please do not freeze" > com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/on-sleep
git add com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/on-sleep
git commit -m "disable freeze workaround"
```

## Warning:

If you apply above changes while daemon is running your system might freeze and you have to restart the system

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html, I think its not possible